# Maintaining order in subseting dataframe in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
V1  V2  V3
1   227 Day1
2   288 Day2
3   243 Day3
4   258 Day4
5   274 Day5
6   245 Day6
7   254 Day7
8   249 Day8
9   230 Day9
10  244 Day10
```

I want to subset `df` where `V1` contains `5,1,7,3` in order. I used `subset(df,V1 %in% c(5,1,7,3))` but what I am getting is:

```
V1  V2  V3
1   227 Day1
3   243 Day3
5   274 Day5
7   254 Day7
```

I want to maintain the order of rows in `V1` to be `5,1,7,3` and not `1,3,5,7`. How can I have the output to be:

```
V1  V2  V3
5   274 Day5
1   227 Day1
7   254 Day7
3   243 Day3
```

Comment: Does `V1` always consist of consecutive integers? :)

Comment: Yes, in the data frame `df` , `V1` is always consecutive.

Comment: See below for a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perhaps overcomplicated, but I would approach this task as follows:

An exemplary data frame:

```
(data2 <- data.frame(V1=1:10, V2=letters[1:10]))
##    V1 V2
## 1   1  a
## 2   2  b
## 3   3  c
## 4   4  d
## 5   5  e
## 6   6  f
## 7   7  g
## 8   8  h
## 9   9  i
## 10 10  j
```

Let's find in which row we have a match (`NA` - no match, `i` - *i*-th value was matched):

```
(m <- match(data2$V1, c(5,1,7,3)))
##  [1]  2 NA  4 NA  1 NA  3 NA NA NA
```

Now we select matching rows matches and permute them accordingly:

```
data2[!is.na(m),][order(na.omit(m)),]
##   V1 V2
## 5  5  e
## 1  1  a
## 7  7  g
## 3  3  c
```

On the other hand, if you know that `V1` consists of consecutive natural numbers (starting from 1), the solution is easy as 1-2-3:

```
data2[c(5,1,7,3),]
##   V1 V2
## 5  5  e
## 1  1  a
## 7  7  g
## 3  3  c
```

Comment: Actually `m<-match(c(5,1,7,3),data2$V1)` would be better. It won't give you all those NA values. Then you can just do `data2[m, ]`

Comment: If V1 is always just consecutive integers, why not just `dat[c(5,1,7,3),]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with `sort=FALSE` and it seems to return in the order that it matches. It will also work if you have repeated values in `V1`. E.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=1:10, V2=letters[1:10])
dat$V1[8] <- 5

dat
#   V1 V2
#1   1  a
#2   2  b
#3   3  c
#4   4  d
#5   5  e
#6   6  f
#7   7  g
#8   5  h
#9   9  i
#10 10  j

merge(data.frame(V1=c(5,1,7,3)),dat,by="V1",sort=FALSE)

#  V1 V2
#1  5  e
#2  5  h
#3  1  a
#4  7  g
#5  3  c
```